# PyQGIS. autosaving on adding feature

Tags: postgis, pyqgis

I try to make autosaving on adding feature and use next code:

```
def autosave():
    iface.activeLayer().commitChanges()
    iface.activeLayer().startEditing()
    iface.actionAddFeature().trigger()
iface.activeLayer().featureAdded.connect(autosave)
```

But `commitChanges()` execute a `featureAdded` and I get a loop. Also I try to use attribute tables validation on search not saved features, like this:

```
def autosave():
    features = iface.activeLayer().getFeatures()
    gid = next(features)[0]
    if "nextval" in str(gid):
        iface.activeLayer().commitChanges()
        iface.activeLayer().startEditing()
        iface.actionAddFeature().trigger()

iface.activeLayer().featureAdded.connect(autosave)
```

And this code executes loop too. How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little trick is to disconnect the signal at the beginning of your function and then reconnect it at the end. Not the nicest of methods but it's one I've used quite often:

```
def autosave():
    iface.activeLayer().featureAdded.disconnect(autosave)
    iface.activeLayer().commitChanges()
    iface.activeLayer().startEditing()
    iface.actionAddFeature().trigger()
    iface.activeLayer().featureAdded.connect(autosave)

iface.activeLayer().featureAdded.connect(autosave)
```